# Is there a way remove SQL Server listener IP on maintenance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, windows, clustering

Is there a any way to stop listening listener on the SQL Server on production server. I want to be sure nobody is trying to connect my production server when it is maintenance mode.

I disabled all users when they have permissions to connect any database. I am sure nobodys can connect any database on that server. But i don't want to be busy my network traffic from any services or application or user while it is on maintenance. So i want to delete Listeners IP to that server.

My possible actions are listed

1. I can delete listener on SQL Server or Listener resource on WSFC.
2. I can delete Ip of listener on    the listener on SQL Server.

Comment: I want to share my experience about this issue. I choosed second option. I deleted Ip of listener on the listener on SQL Server for maintenance. And add it again when i finished my work. Everything is fine.

Comment: You should start the server in single user mode.  Disabling IP of listener doesn't guarantee there isn't local processes connecting.  Your solution is clever but potentially incorrect/not guaranteed to work in all environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better approach than deactivating all listeners is to set your instance in single user mode. Single user mode is recommended for maintenance work and dont allow normal users to connect to the instance. you do not need to change any listeners and permissions on your database. Check [this msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236.aspx).